# Angularjs FormGen plugin json from database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['fg', 'ngSanitize', 'markdown']);

myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, mySchema, formService) {
    debugger;
    var myData;
    formService.GetCountyForm('', '').then(function (d) {

                myData = d.data[0].FormSchema;
                schema = myData;

                //myApp.value('mySchema', { myData });
                myFormData = myData;

            });

    debugger;

    $scope.myForm = {
        schema: mySchema
    };
});

debugger;
myApp.value('mySchema', {
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "firstName",
      "displayName": "First name",
      "validation": {
        "messages": {},
        "required": true
      },
      "placeholder": "Enter your first name here",
      "tooltip": "Enter your first name here"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "lastName",
      "displayName": "Last name",
      "validation": {
        "messages": {},
        "required": true
      },
      "placeholder": "Enter your last name here",
      "tooltip": "Enter your last name here"
    },
    {
      "type": "radiobuttonlist",
      "name": "sex",
      "displayName": "Sex",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "male",
          "text": "Male"
        },
        {
          "value": "female",
          "text": "Female"
        }
      ],
      "value": "male"
    },
    {
      "type": "email",
      "name": "email",
      "displayName": "Email",
      "validation": {
        "messages": {}
      },
      "placeholder": "Enter your email address here",
      "tooltip": "Enter your email address here"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkboxlist",
      "name": "color",
      "displayName": "Colors",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "red",
          "text": "Red"
        },
        {
          "value": "blue",
          "text": "Blue"
        },
        {
          "value": "green",
          "text": "Green"
        }
      ],
      "value": {}
    }
  ]
});


myApp.factory('formService', function ($http) {
    var fac = {};

    fac.GetCountyForm = function (stateCode, countyName) {
        //alert($(".select4 :selected").text() + " " + countyName);
        //replacing statecode with statename

        return $http({
            url: '/data/GetFormSchema',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ stateCode: stateCode, countyName: countyName }),
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        });
    }


    return fac;
});
```

trying to integrate json form in MVC. https://github.com/McNull/angular-form-gen
I have json stored in form but somehow it is not loading, if I hard code the json value,
myApp.value('mySchema' then my form is loading but when I try to set the json value from db it doesn't work. Can someone help with this. Thanks in advance.

Create a plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/iVHfc62Z5n39AfNfgUHL?p=preview
If I load json value from db it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am trying to create a form based on a  json retrieved from database too...

Comment: Nope buddy. I changed my approach as this doesn't work as I expected

Comment: Did you switch to a different framework? Can you, please, describe the way you've changed your approach?

Comment: @cristid9 no I actually dropped this idea and now it is a plain form. I was running behind the schedule so couldn't invest much time on this. But I will certainly like to see this working. Let me know if I can be of some help